# How to re render component from main.js file in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

I want to rerender my component `notfication.vue` from main.js.

main.js file is available globally.

In this file, I am receiving notification. After receiving the notification, I want to rerender component.

```
PushNotifications.addListener('pushNotificationReceived', 
  async (notification) => {
    // Rerender notification component from here

    notificationComponent ???

  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use state management for example vuex, put `notificationComponentKey` as a state and put it on your component `<notification-component :key="notificationComponentKey"` and everytime you get a notification you do `notificationComponentKey++;` which rerenders the component.